# debian linux gvfs-copy command not found

Tags: linux, command-line, manpage, gzip, debian-jessie

**Background:**

I am trying to copy files from a raspberry pi 3 (raspbian jessie) to an Android phone connected as an mtp device. I want to do it over the command line so that I can write a script to automate it. If I try to use a simple cp command, I get a permissions error. I read [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193132/unable-to-perform-file-operations-on-a-mtp-device-mounted-via-gvfs-operation-n) that I should use gvfs-copy instead for transferring files to an mtp device.

**Problem:**

When I try to run gvfs-copy in the command line I get a "command not found" error. I can see the command in the man pages, I just can't run it.

If I run `whereis gvfs-copy` I get `gvfs-copy: /usr/share/man/man1/gvfs-copy.1.gz`

If I run `whereis cp` I get `cp: /bin/cp /usr/share/man/man1/cp.1.gz`

Do I need to extract gvfs-copy.1.gz to /bin/gvfs-copy to be able to run it? And why would some commands be ready to run and others not?

Answer (score 3):

I just had to install the package gvfs-bin, which I would have seen if I read more of the answers on the original post I linked to.

I still don't understand why a command in the man pages wouldn't be installed already, that seems misleading to me.